# Webpack vs gulp-webpack

Tags: webpack, gulp, gulp-webpack

I'm trying to task webpack from gulp to process a directory that contains .js files. I'm using gulp-webpack 1.5.0. Gulp task is defined as:

```
return gulp.src(joinPath(config.aliasify.dest, 'index.js'))
            .pipe(webpack( require('./_____webpack.config.js') ))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

_____webpack.config.js is:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    stats: {
        // Configure the console output
        errorDetails: true,
        colors: true,
        modules: true,
        reasons: true
    },
    progress: true,
    entry: "./out/js/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    }

}
```

It fails miserably. There seems to be problems with JSON files :

> ERROR in ./~/aws-sdk/apis/cognito-idp-2016-04-18.paginators.json
>   Module parse failed: /Users/omatrot/Projects/trash/reactxp/samples/hello-world/node_modules/aws-sdk/apis/cognito-idp-2016-04-18.paginators.json Unexpected token (2:14)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:14)

Running webpack on the same directory with the-apparently- same configuration works fine.

```
webpack.config.ts file is:

import * as webpack from 'webpack';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: "./out/js/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

};

export default config;
```

> webpack --display-error-details --progress --colors
>
> Hash: 0a378df14f58624d244f
>   Version: webpack 2.2.1
>   Time: 3920ms
>           Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>       bundle.js  3.07 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
>   bundle.js.map  3.71 MB       0  [emitted]         main
>      [8] ./~/reactxp/index.js 146 bytes {0} [built]
>    [112] ./out/js/ExercisesStore.js 3.29 kB {0} [built]
>    [120] ./~/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/CognitoRefreshToken.js 1.4 kB {0} [built]
>    [126] ./~/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/index.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
>    [217] ./out/js/App3.js 14.4 kB {0} [built]
>    [278] ./~/jwt-decode/lib/index.js 680 bytes {0} [built]
>    [490] ./out/js/AlertAndPromptWeb.js 3.4 kB {0} [built]
>    [494] ./out/js/EditExerciseAttributePropertiesPanel.js 10.4 kB {0} [built]
>    [495] ./out/js/EditExerciseAttributesValuesPanel.js 9.4 kB {0} [built]
>    [496] ./out/js/EditExerciseCategoryPropertiesPanel.js 5.78 kB {0} [built]
>    [497] ./out/js/EditExerciseMainPropertiesPanel.js 4.91 kB {0} [built]
>    [498] ./out/js/ExercicesTopLevelView.js 13.7 kB {0} [built]
>    [502] ./out/js/LogHelper.js 791 bytes {0} [built]
>    [504] ./out/js/asynccognito.js 2.08 kB {0} [built]
>    [505] ./out/js/index.js 599 bytes {0} [built]
>       + 491 hidden modules

I'm doing it wrong but I can't find what it is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, while reinstalling node modules I was presented a warning message that led me to a resolution:

> npm WARN deprecated gulp-webpack@1.5.0: Renamed to https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stream

So I switched to this module and it worked immediately, after removal of the progress configuration option that is deprecated.